# Using universal selector (*) in conjunction with the adjacent selector (+)

Tags: html, css

When is the right time to use the universal selector in combination with the adjacent selector in CSS?

For instance:

```
* + fieldset {...}
```

Comment: this is equivalent to `fieldset:not(:first-child)`

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Comment: there is a good article describing the use of the selectors of that kind: http://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls

Comment: thank you for sharing this article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be good when `fieldset` is not the `:first-child`.

The below snippet demonstrates the best use-case:

```css
* + fieldset {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    ...
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div>
  <p>...</p>
  <fieldset>
    ...
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot

Comment: yeah i wanted to accept it but couldn't. i will accept later